# I want software to slow down my typing and increase my accuracy

Tags: keyboard, software-recommendation, utilities

**Problem**

I'd like to teach myself to type slower and more accurately.

**Solutions?**

I was thinking of

- playing a sound when I press backspace
- displaying wpm/accuracy in the menubar

**Aside**

The reason I want to do this is I went to a conference the other day where I saw a live coding session where the guy didn't make a **SINGLE TYPO** for the 30 minutes I watched,  - and apparently, he had not made a mistake for the 30 minutes before.

Comment: When I get time I'm going to try and write an apple script that plays a sound on keypress. [detect keypress discussion](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=9638)

Comment: Look at typing tutors - you just have to practise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) to play a sound when you press delete. For example save this file as `~/Library/Application Support/Karabiner/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <vkopenurldef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SHELL_BEEP</name>
    <url type="shell">afplay /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ScreenReader.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Sounds/BrailleChordFailed.aiff</url>
  </vkopenurldef>
  <item>
    <name>custom</name>
    <identifier>custom</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::DELETE, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::DELETE, KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SHELL_BEEP</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then open the Karabiner application, press the ReloadXML button and enable the setting.

You could also use [Master Key](http://macinmind.com/?area=app&app=masterkey&pg=info) or [TypeRacer](http://play.typeracer.com) to practice typing pieces of plain text.

Comment: Fantastic! I chose the more annoying "Ellipsis.aiff"